# A question for regularity of solutions to wave equation

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

let $T>0$ and suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary. Let $g \in L^\infty(0,T;H^1(\partial \Omega))$ and consider the wave equation
\begin{equation}\label{pf0}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
\partial^2_t u-\Delta u=0\,\quad &\text{on $(0,T)\times \Omega$},
\\
u=g\,\quad &\text{on $(0,T)\times \partial \Omega$,}\\
u(0,x)=\partial_t u(0,x)=0\quad &\text{on $\Omega$}\\
\end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Is it true that the above equation admits a unique solution
$$ u \in C^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))\cap C(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$$
and that $\partial_\nu u \in L^{\infty}(0,T;H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega))$, where $\nu$ is the normal unit vector field on $\partial \Omega$?